# Specify the specific heat of a material with Revit 2017 Python API

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

With Revit 2017 Python API, I am trying to create new materials, and then assembling some of these to create new type of walls.
It goes pretty well for all properties, **except** for the specific heat!

Basically, what I do is:

1. create a thermalAsset:

   ```
   themalA = ThermalAsset('Test', ThermalMaterialType.Solid)
   ```
2. Set the different thermal properties for that thermal asset (dummy values):

   ```
   thermalA.ThermalConductivity = 0.01

   thermalA.SpecificHeat = 0.001

   thermalA.Density = 1000.0
   ```
3. Then I create a PropertySetElement with that thermal asset:

   ```
   pse = PropertySetElement.Create(doc, thermalA)
   ```
4. Then I assign it to my material (that I previously created):

   ```
   mat.SetMaterialAspectByPropertySet(MaterialAspect.Thermal, pse)
   ```

Afetr that, I take a look in my materials list in Revit, and look at the thermal properties. Everything seems ok, except the Specific Heat, which **remains** at 0.0239 btu/(lb. F), whatever the value I input when I assign the specific heat. Density is ok, thermal conductivity is ok, but not specific heat.

I got no error message.

What am I missing?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value you specify in the expected unit? Feet per Kelvin, squared-second. Cf., http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/04/whats-new-in-the-revit-2014-api.html > ThermalAsset.SpecificHeat.

I submitted this to the development team for further analysis as issue **REVIT-111206** [API: setting ThermalAsset SpecificHeat fails]. Can you please provide a full reproducible case for them to test, e.g., a minimal RVT model with an embedded macro to run, cf., http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#1b? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Actually, there is a subsequent question to what you are pointing: I read that comment about the units, and I ask myself if these units for specific heat are correct?? I don't think so. Specific heat (per mass) should be in `J/(kg K)`, which is `m²/(K s²)`, which could also be converted to `btu/(lb °F)`... but there is no way to go from there to `ft/(K s²)`.. is it? I'll make a reproducible case.

Comment: Ok, here is a reproducible case, on a single wall: <https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kxakzg8fqautkvt/AAAAW4kIOMkKioWcWNmFM66Na?dl=0>. Open the file, then copy paste the python script in the Interactive Python Shell, and execute. It will produce 2 new materials. For these 2 new materials, the thermal conductivity varies, but not the specific heat (which should).

Comment: Thank you, added it to the development database issue.