# Specific Heat units specification via Revit 2017 API

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell

Referring to a previous question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188885/specify-the-specific-heat-of-a-material-with-revit-2017-python-api), I also have a problem with the units required by Revit. In the RevitAPI.chm help, I read for the ThermalAsset.SpecificHeat Property that "Values are in feet per Kelvin, squared-second (ft/(K s²))...". These units can't be converted to J/(kg K), if I'm not mistaken.
So, I guess it is actually (ft²/(K s²)). Can someone confirm this?

Thanks!

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this for you with the development team.

They confirm what you suspected:

You are right.

The unit for specific heat in the thermal asset library is J/(g·°C).

The units available in Revit Project Units UI are J/(g·°C)  and BTU/(lb·°F) = ft²/( s²·°F).

So, the help file should be corrected to read, "Values are in squared-feet per Kelvin, squared-second (ft²/(K s²))...".